# Finding min element using .index() gives unexpected result

Tags: python, list

I don't understand what is wrong in this list

```
L = [20,5,4,85,96,75,3,3.1]
m = min(i for i in L if L.index(i)%2==1)

print L.index(m), m
```

the output as I expected:

```
7 3.1
```

but when I change the last number in list 3.1 to 3

```
L = [20,5,4,85,96,75,3,3]
m = min(i for i in L if L.index(i)%2==1)

print L.index(m), m
```

the output was not 3:

```
1 5
```

please explain the reason

Comment: .index finds the *first* index, so neither 3 appears to be at an odd index

Comment: FWIW for finding the smallest num in an odd index you can just do `min(L[1::2])` see   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: thank you @ jonrsharpe and @DeepSpace for your explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumerate()`, to get position for each value in the list:

```
L = [20,5,4,85,96,75,3,3]
m = min(j for (i,j) in enumerate(L) if i%2==1)
```

Output:

```
6 3
```